# Intel HD Graphics, Switchable Graphics, and 3D Acceleration in Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, amd-radeon, intel-graphics, 3d-graphics, switchable-graphics

In my system I have two Display Adapters in a Host with Windows 10:

1. Intel HD Graphics 4000
2. AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series

The DirectX Diagnostic Tool showed that:

1. Intel is Full Display Device Type
2. AMD is Render-Only Display Device

OpenGL Extensions Viewer showed that:

1. The Renderer is Intel
2. OpenGL version is 4
3. DirectX version is 9c

Display Adapter Properties showed that
the Adapter Type is Intel.

I would appreciate your help to configure my system to use the 3D Acceleration resource in Virtual Machines.

I tried the 3D Acceleration option in VirtualBox, but without success (with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 guests).

The DirectX Diagnostic Tool in the guest with Windows 8.1 showed that:

1. The Device is VirtualBox Graphics Adapter for Windows 8
2. Processor Type is VirtualBox VESA BIOS
3. Principal Driver is VBoxDispD3D.dll

The GLView in the guest Windows 8.1 showed that:

1. Renderer = GDI Generic
2. Adapter RAM = N/A
3. OpenGL Version = 1.1
4. DirectX Version = 9.0c

In the guest Ubuntu 14.04 appeared:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
OpenGL vendor string:   Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Chromium 1.9

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Using VMware Workstation 12 Player I obtained the following result (for the guest with Ubuntu 14.04):

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 10.3.2

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes
Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Also using the GPU-Z app I could see that the AMD video card was used when the 3D Simulation was launched in the guest.